# \hdashline in tikzpicture-environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, hline

I've a trouble with this code.
I'd like a \hdashline, but Overleaf gives me an error, why?

My code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Ancora su Sarrus}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.center)]
\tikzset{Barr/.style = {opacity=.4,line width=4 mm,line cap=round,color=#1},
         Sigp/.style = {circle,  fill=blue, fill opacity=0.4, text opacity=1,
                        minimum size=4mm, left, inner sep=0pt,
                        node contents={$+$}},
         Sigm/.style = {Sigp,fill=red, node contents={\vphantom{+}$-$}},
         Prod/.style = {rounded corners=5pt,
                        fill=#1,  fill opacity=0.4, text opacity=1, inner sep=2pt, right},
         }
% the matrices
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes,
             column sep=1ex,
             row sep=1ex
             ]
{ a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}  \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}  \\ \hline %I'd like a \hdashline, but Overleaf gives me an error, why?
  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}  \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \\
};
\draw[semithick]    (A-1-1.north west) -- (A-3-1.south west)
                    (A-1-3.north east) -- (A-3-3.south east);
\draw [Barr=blue] (A-1-1.north west) node[Sigp] to (A-3-3.south east) node[Prod=blue]{$a_{11}\cdot a_{22}\cdot a_{33}$}
                  (A-2-1.north west) node[Sigp] to (A-4-3.south east) node[Prod=blue]{$a_{21}\cdot a_{32}\cdot a_{13}$}
                  (A-3-1.north west) node[Sigp] to (A-5-3.south east) node[Prod=blue]{$a_{31}\cdot a_{12}\cdot a_{23}$};

\draw [Barr=red]  (A-3-1.south west) node[Sigm] to (A-1-3.north east) node[Prod=red]{$a_{31}\cdot a_{22}\cdot a_{13}$}
                  (A-4-1.south west) node[Sigm] to (A-2-3.north east) node[Prod=red]{$a_{11}\cdot a_{32}\cdot a_{23}$}
                  (A-5-1.south west) node[Sigm] to (A-3-3.north east) node[Prod=red]{$a_{21}\cdot a_{12}\cdot a_{33}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I've load all packages that I'm using. (I use these packages because I'm writing a book of Linear Algebra)
Thank you so much in advanced for the help!

Comment: pdfLaTeX. However I already edit all

Comment: I already cancel pstricks with pdflatex

Comment: I already explain what my problem is. Again, My problem is this: How can I create a \hdashline with tikzpicture? What does \hdashline substitute?

Comment: most of the symbols added by stmaryrd are also in stix I suspect but maybe there are a few that got left?

Comment: For now, stix with stmaryrd are not a problem for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a matrix of nodes is a tikz picture and you can draw any tikz path between the nodes, I added a dashed green line where I think you indicated you wanted a dahed line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
%%% default \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%%% xcolor \usepackage{color}
%%% mathtools \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%% stix2 (mostly) \usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Ancora su Sarrus}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.center)]
\tikzset{Barr/.style = {opacity=.4,line width=4 mm,line cap=round,color=#1},
         Sigp/.style = {circle,  fill=blue, fill opacity=0.4, text opacity=1,
                        minimum size=4mm, left, inner sep=0pt,
                        node contents={$+$}},
         Sigm/.style = {Sigp,fill=red, node contents={\vphantom{+}$-$}},
         Prod/.style = {rounded corners=5pt,
                        fill=#1,  fill opacity=0.4, text opacity=1, inner sep=2pt, right},
         }
% the matrices
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes,
             column sep=1ex,
             row sep=1ex
             ]
{ a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}  \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}  \\ %\hline %I'd like a \hdashline, but Overleaf gives me an error, why?
  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}  \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \\
};
\draw[semithick]    (A-1-1.north west) -- (A-3-1.south west)
                    (A-1-3.north east) -- (A-3-3.south east);
\draw [Barr=blue] (A-1-1.north west) node[Sigp] to (A-3-3.south east) node[Prod=blue]{$a_{11}\cdot a_{22}\cdot a_{33}$}
                  (A-2-1.north west) node[Sigp] to (A-4-3.south east) node[Prod=blue]{$a_{21}\cdot a_{32}\cdot a_{13}$}
                  (A-3-1.north west) node[Sigp] to (A-5-3.south east) node[Prod=blue]{$a_{31}\cdot a_{12}\cdot a_{23}$};

\draw [Barr=red]  (A-3-1.south west) node[Sigm] to (A-1-3.north east) node[Prod=red]{$a_{31}\cdot a_{22}\cdot a_{13}$}
                  (A-4-1.south west) node[Sigm] to (A-2-3.north east) node[Prod=red]{$a_{11}\cdot a_{32}\cdot a_{23}$}
                  (A-5-1.south west) node[Sigm] to (A-3-3.north east) node[Prod=red]{$a_{21}\cdot a_{12}\cdot a_{33}$};
\draw [color=green, dashed] (A-3-1.south west) to  (A-3-3.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, thank you so much!!! Best Regards